# Getting the time until next Sunday with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

So I have moment JS, and I need to display the time until next sunday in human readable words:

`Next Sunday will be in 5 days, 4 hours, 30 minutes, and 10 seconds.`

Moment has a `from` method but not an `until` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a function moment.fromNow() which shows things like "in 5 months" or "3 years ago".

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: That needs to know the date of next sunday.  This doesn't answer how if it's just the arbitrary next Sunday.

Answer (score 4):

why don't you try moment#to

```
 a.to(b) // "in a day"
```

as for the next sunday,

```
moment().endOf("week");
```

might do the trick.

so basically the code you would require will be

```
var now = moment();
var nextSunday = moment().endOf("week");
now.to(nextSunday)
```